# Error: [LWC error]: that use the `lwc:dom="manual"` - adding columns to datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm not sure what's the cause of this error and whenever I add the following code in .js file then I see this error,

PS: Before posting the question I searched and I did not find an answer

> Looks like there's a problem.
>
> Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem
> continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID
> shown here and any other related details.

```
const COLS = [
    {label: 'Name', fieldName: 'link', type: 'url', typeAttributes: {label: {fieldName: 'FullName'}}},
    {label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email'},
    {label: 'Account', fieldName: "accountLink", type: 'url', typeAttributes: {label: {fieldName: 'AccountName'}}},
    {label: "Mailing Address", fieldName: 'MailingAddress'},
    { fieldName: "actions", type: 'action', typeAttributes: {rowActions: ACTIONS}}
]
```

html:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Custom Contact List View">
        <div slot="actions">
            <lightning-button label="Create Contact" onclick={navigateToNewRecordPage}></lightning-button>
            <lightning-button label="Delete Selected Contacts" onclick={deleteSelectedContacts}></lightning-button>

        </div>
        <div class="slds-card__body_inner">
            <p>Selected Contacts: {selectedContactsLen}</p>

            <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-p-bottom_x-small slds-p-left_x-small">
                <lightning-input type="search" onchange={handleSearch}></lightning-input>
            </div>
            
            <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={contacts}
                columns={cols}
                onrowselection={handleRowSelection}
                onrowaction={handleRowAction} > 
            </lightning-datatable>
        </div>

    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

.JS:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';

import getContacts from "@salesforce/apex/contactlistviewController.getContacts";
 
const COLS = [
    {label: 'Name', fieldName: 'link', type: 'url', typeAttributes: {label: {fieldName: 'FullName'}}},
    {label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email'},
    {label: 'Account', fieldName: "accountLink", type: 'url', typeAttributes: {label: {fieldName: 'AccountName'}}},
    {label: "Mailing Address", fieldName: 'MailingAddress'},
    { fieldName: "actions", type: 'action', typeAttributes: {rowActions: ACTIONS}}
]

export default class Contactlistview extends LightningElement {

}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know much (OK, next to nothing) about LWCs and I haven't touched JS in a while. Does it matter if you have a mixture of single quotes `'` and double quotes `"` in the same block? E.g., one excerpt of your JS code looks like: `{label: 'Account', fieldName: "accountLink",...`

Comment: Javascript is ok with thhat

Comment: Two things. First, if you get an error like this, you should check the F12 Developer Console, and copy-paste that error verbatim, if any. Secondly, without seeing more context, not sure if we can help you. If you want, I can write a practical app that demonstrates adding columns, and see if that helps you, but I don't think the error is specifically "here" in the parts you've written.

Comment: okay finally figured out the cause of this error message I was missing `ACTIONS` error message is misleading, you guys can try not adding ACTIONS and you will see the same strange error :) 
after adding the ACTIONS `const ACTIONS = [{label: 'Delete', name: 'delete'}]` all is good now.

Comment: @NickKahn Would be great to put that as an accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

In my .JS code I was missing ACTIONS

```
const ACTIONS = [{label: 'Delete', name: 'delete'}]
```